# using if condition in drop down in angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add a filter to a dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  <option selected value="0">{{ first_value }}</option>
  <option *ngFor="let i of data" [value]="i.id">
     {{i.city_name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

How can I add a filter like `*ngIf="city_country == 'US'"`?

Comment: Why not filter the `data` array with that condition?

Comment: Why do this in the template? Just filter the data array in the backing code.

Comment: @eko @R. Richards, Because depending on a env file, I'm trying to filter it on Frontend. For if env.name == 'X', if can display only `city_country == 'US'`, if env.name == 'Y', I want to display only `city_country == 'UK'`.

Comment: This html is part of a component and that component has a `data` field, right? You can make this filtering operation in your component rather than doing it on the html. It doesn't matter where this filter is coming from. Your component.ts file still Frontend.

Comment: @eko Thanks. I have added the filter in my component. But is it not acceptable to add a check in HTML part?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that

Answer (score 1):

As we are using structural directive we couldn't use two on same tag.

so either you can use new variable to get all the city's within US or we can have a get function to get all the city's with in US

```
// inside component class    
get citiesWithinUS() {
  return this.data.filter(x => x.city_country === 'US')
}


// inside html page
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  <option selected value="0">{{ first_value }}</option>
  <option *ngFor="let i of citiesWithinUS" [value]="i.id">
     {{i.city_name}}
  </option>
</select>
```